# How to remove several spaces at the beginning of the line only

Tags: python

I've got a file that look like this:

```
   TOTO   TATA   
TUTU   TITI  PAPA
         AAA BBB   CCCC
```

And I'd like to be able to substitute only the spaces starting a line with something else.

eg:

```
eeeTOTO   TATA   
TUTU   TITI  PAPA
eeeeeeeeeAAA BBB   CCCC
```

It looks simple, but it does not work for me.

this is what I tried wrongly:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#open the file
fs = open("./Tst.tst", 'r')
fd = open("./Out.tst", 'w')

print fs.read()
print fd.read()

for line in fs:
    fd.write(line)
    for char in line:
        if (" ") in char:
            char = char.replace(" ", "e" )
            fd.write(char)
        else:
            print char

fd.close()
fs.close()
```

Comment: What "does not work"? what have you tried?

Comment: You are looking for a strip function and most possibly the lstrip. But I really think you should show us what you tried :) https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lstrip

Comment: @AntonvBR: strip won't *replace* characters, only remove them.

Comment: @MartijnPieters True, I got ahead of myself.

Comment: [`replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) is a great place to start exploring

Comment: #!/usr/bin/python

#open the file
fs = open("./Tst.tst", 'r')
fd = open("./Out.tst", 'w')

print fs.read()
print fd.read()

for line in fs:
    fd.write(line)
    for char in line:
        if (" ") in char:
            char = char.replace(" ", "e" )
            fd.write(char)
        else:
            print char

fd.close()
fs.close()

Comment: right, all is easy lol, even for me

Comment: I don't believe there is a simple non-regex solution.

Comment: It seems that on the output file, `fd`, you are just writing the lines starting with whitespaces. Is this what you want to do? This is not what you stated on the initial post.

Comment: non regex would require iterating over each line: while char == '  ': replace(' ', 'e') but coldspeed is pretty much correct this is a good one for 're'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` with a callback:

```
In [979]: import re

In [980]: for x in lines.splitlines():
     ...:     print(re.sub('^ +', lambda k: 'e' * len(k.group(0)), x))
     ...:     
eeeTOTO   TATA   
TUTU   TITI  PAPA
eeeeeeeeeAAA BBB   CCCC
```

---

As a complete example, consider:

```
def foo(k):
    'e' * len(k.group(0))

with open("./In.txt", 'r') as fs, open("./Out.txt", 'w') as fd:
    lines = fs.read()
    for x in lines.splitlines():
        print(re.sub('^ +', foo, file=fd)
```

When a match is encountered, the match object is passed to the callback, which returns another string as the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

For a non-regex solution, this is what I could come up with.

**Disclaimer**

It works fine for the sample input but you'd have to run more tests on it to clear out bugs; if any.

```
# text = '   TOTO   TATA   '
# text = 'TUTU   TITI  PAPA'
text = '         AAA BBB   CCCC'

character_spot = False
num_empty_spots = 0
unwanted_text = ' '
replacement_text = 'e'

# this loop counts the number of empty spots in your string
for char in text:
  if char != unwanted_text and not character_spot:
    character_spot = True
    print 'Character exists'
  else:
    if not character_spot:
      num_empty_spots += 1
      print 'Empty spot'

# this replaces the first 'num_empty_spots' occurences of the unwanted_text
text = text.replace(unwanted_text, replacement_text, num_empty_spots)  
print text
```

Comment: Anytime.Was it helpful? Or did u opt for the regex option?

Comment: both are good. Using the number is smart, I did not think of it. :)